# TinyMCE - Writing plugin that insert content on top

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am trying to write a plugin for TinyMCE with a feature to add content to the beginning of the content. I know the following command which will insert content at the current location of the cursor. How do I force it to insert it at the beginning of the content?

```
tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceInsertRawHTML', false, "halo world");
tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "halo world");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you will need to set the cursor location to the beginning of the editor content.
you may use the function setCursorLocation:

```
 ed.selection.setCursorLocation(ed.getBody().firstChild, 0); // node to set the cursor to, second param is offset
```

Comment: Thanks. I was about to look into the core of tinyMCE.

Answer (score 0):

The `setCursorLocation` will move the cursor to the position of the first html element's first content character. This means that if your current html content looks like:
`<div>abcd</div>`
then the `setCursorLocation` will move the cursor between the `<div>` and the `abcd`. In some cases this is not acceptable. So another solution would be: `ed.setContent('yourText' + ed.getContent())`.